Spring Boot: Throw a custom Exception when a response other than a specific response type is returned
I am developing an API with Spring Boot. I want the API responses to be only of a certain type (ResponseEntity). When the response is of another type, I want to throw a custom Exception so that the user gets a specific error message.
public class MyResponseType {
    private String message;
    private int statusCode;
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

// **This is OK**
    @GetMapping("/example-success")
    public ResponseEntity<MyResponseType> getExampleSuccess() {
        MyResponseType response = new MyResponseType("This is a valid response", 200);
        return new ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

// **When invoked, this endpoint should throw an InvalidResponseTypeException.**
    @GetMapping("/example-failure")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getExampleFailure() {
        // **We return a response of type String instead of MyResponseType.**
        String response = "This is an invalid response";
        return new ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}

// **Exception class**
public class InvalidResponseTypeException extends RuntimeException {
    public InvalidResponseTypeException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}


You can control the type of response you want to return, by just 'not returning any other type of response'. Your requirement is unclear.

Before throwing an exception, it would be interesting to ask some questions like :  Do I only need a custom error to return to the user in a specific controller or endpoint ? Or do I have to set a consistent error responses across the API with  centralizing error handling ?
Depending on the need, you can add or not exception throwing. So you have two approches :
1 - Returning a ResponseEntity with an Error Code Directly (for quick responses with minimal logic): lets say all we want is returning an error because we know that the response is not the right one :
@GetMapping("/example-failure")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getExampleFailure() {
        //Return a response of type String instead of MyResponseType.
        String response = "This is an invalid response";
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }

2 - If you really need an exception handling knowing that exceptions are often reserved for truly exceptional cases or errors that need to propagate up the stack but can also be used for consistent error responses across your API.

One of the best practices for handling exceptions globally is to use @ControllerAdvice :
    @GetMapping("/example-failure")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getExampleFailure() {
        // **Throw a new exception**
        throw new InvalidResponseTypeException("Item not found")

    }
    ...


    // Here The GlobalExceptionHandler declared in the controller advice class, catches the thrown exception and responds with a consistent error
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

        @ExceptionHandler(InvalidResponseTypeException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleNotFoundException(InvalidResponseTypeException ex) {
            ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("NOT_ACCEPTABLE", ex.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }

        // You can also have in the same class other exception handlers...
    }





Thank you for your response! I realize I might not have fully clarified what I’m trying to achieve. In my project, I want to enforce that any new endpoints added must have a response type of ResponseEntity. In other words, if a different response type is used, I would like an error to be thrown before the response is sent to the client.
The goal here is to ensure consistency across all API responses in the project, so I need a way to prevent any response type other than ResponseEntity from being returned.
